# RMI to HTTP protocol

Tags: java, swing, http, rmi

Our project is a traditional project which is using **RMI** to do the communication between a Server and a Client (using **Swing**).

Recently, we want to change protocol from RMI to HTTP(for the firewall safety) **without changing too much** original code(keep original Server logic and Swing GUI).

Is there any good and mature way to do the transition? Thanks.

Comment: Did you build your code using GoF and/or Java Core EE Patterns in mind?
If you have some sort of Business Delegate Façade you could replace the Service implementation (RMI) by an HTTP/REST implementation.

Comment: No, just use the java core without EE or any container.

Comment: Did you write a Java Interface to define the services? That would allow you to replace it with minimal coding effort.
A more 'extreme' way would be to use Java Proxies to replace the runtime implementation with the new one. (complex and not too easy to test)

Comment: I see your point. That's good way. So i still need to deploy my server code into a servlet container, and then provide a rest API for original RMI service interface, right?

Comment: Of course HTTP (likewise REST) is a bit slower. See also docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/rmi/spec/rmi-arch6.html

Comment: JasonS , that is correct. You would still need to write a Rest API on the server side on top of the RMI service interface, but this is the easy part. Besides, depending how you defined your service interface in the server side, you can get rid of RMI.
As @JoopEggen wrote, there is a trade off between the security and performance aspects of the change.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I think i will try to make the HTTP tunnelling way work first, maybe the REST way later (cause it seems to involve more changes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your code as-is with the RMI/HTTP tunnelling that's built in to RMI. You just install the RMI-CGI servlet that's distributed with the sample code, configure it appropriately, and Bob's your auntie.

See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/rmi/spec/rmi-arch6.html). Thanks to @JoopEggen for the link.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with this tunnel, do you have any sample?  Really appreciate it. @EJP